# Probability of one or more events occurring all with different probabilities

Tags: probability, combinatorics

For example imagine if a horse is racing in 5 different races, how would you calculate the probability of that horse winning 3 out of the 5 races. With the probabilities of  $\frac{1}{2.2}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{3.3}, \frac{1}{10}$ and $\frac{1}{5}$ respectively.

I am not a math's expert, so explanation of the how to use any formulas would be appreciated.

Currently to get an approximation I simply multiply the odds of the two favorites then multiply that again with the sum of the other probabilities. $(\frac{1}{2.2} \times \frac{1}{3.3}) \times (\frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5}$)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a possible point of ambiguity.  To a mathematician, $2.2/1$ (for example) translates into a win factor of $\displaystyle \frac{1}{3.2}$.

This corresponds to a payout of $2.2$ **to** $1$.  However, it is not uncommon for a casino (for example) to use the syntax $2.2/1$ to represent a payout of $2.2$ **for** $1$, which implies that if you win, you get back $2.2$, instead of $(2.2 + 1 = 3.2)$.

In the response below, I am going to assume that $2.2/1$ signifies a payout of $2.2$ **to** $1$, rather than $2.2$ **for** $1$.

---

Easiest to use your example for illustration, for an **exact answer**.

First, you have to convert each *odds* into a probability $p$ such that $0 < p < 1.$

In horse racing *parlance*, $X/1$ translates into
$\displaystyle p = \frac{1}{X + 1}.$

So, letting $p_k$ denote the probability of the horse winning race $k$, you have that

$p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4, p_5~~$ equal

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{3.2}, \frac{1}{5}, \frac{1}{4.3}, \frac{1}{11}, \frac{1}{6},~~$ respectively.

Set $q_1, q_2, q_3, q_4, q_5~~$ equal to

$(1 - p_1), (1 - p_2), (1 - p_3), (1 - p_4), (1 - p_5)~~$ respectively.

Per your example, I am assuming that you want the probability of *exactly* $3$ wins for the horse, rather than (for example) *at least* $3$ wins.

Unfortunately, there isn't much of a shortcut.  First, I will show the brute force method, and then discuss possible shortcuts.

There are $\displaystyle \binom{5}{3}$ different possibilities for which of the $3$ races that the horse wins.  The brute force method is to add together the following $10$ terms:

$p_1 \times p_2 \times p_3 \times q_4 \times q_5$. 
$p_1 \times p_2 \times q_3 \times p_4 \times q_5$. 
$p_1 \times p_2 \times q_3 \times q_4 \times p_5$. 
$p_1 \times q_2 \times p_3 \times p_4 \times q_5$. 
$p_1 \times q_2 \times p_3 \times q_4 \times p_5$.

$p_1 \times q_2 \times q_3 \times p_4 \times p_5$. 
$q_1 \times q_2 \times p_3 \times p_4 \times p_5$. 
$q_1 \times p_2 \times q_3 \times p_4 \times p_5$. 
$q_1 \times p_2 \times p_3 \times q_4 \times p_5$. 
$q_1 \times p_2 \times p_3 \times p_4 \times q_5$.

A shortcut *of sorts* is to notice that the first $6$ terms all have the horse winning the 1st race.  This corresponds to $\displaystyle \binom{4}{2} = 6$, which represents that there are $6$ ways of choosing which of the other $2$ races the horse wins.

So, you could ignore the $p_1$ factor, brute force compute the sum of the 1st 6 terms, using only $4$ factors each (i.e. where the $p_1$ factor is excluded in each of the $6$ computations), and then multiply the sum of these $6$ terms by $p_1$.  This would get you the actual sum of the first $6$ terms.

Similarly, you could notice that the last $4$ terms all have a factor of $q_1$.  So, you could brute force compute these last $4$ terms, excluding the $q_1$ factor in each term, and then *collectively* apply the $q_1$ factor.

A (quick) estimate is to notice that the probability of the horse winning the $4th$ race is very small $\left(
\text{i.e.} ~ \displaystyle \frac{1}{11}\right)$.  So, if you assume that the horse loses that race, then instead of having to sum $\displaystyle \binom{5}{3}$ terms, you only have to sum $\displaystyle \binom{4}{3}$ terms.

There are certainly other *approximation games* that can be played.  For example, instead of simply ignoring the $6$ possibilities that correspond to the horse winning the $4$th race, you could reason as follows:

In exactly $3$ of the $10$ races, the horse wins race $3$ and loses race $4$.  Call this group A.  In exactly $3$ of the races, the horse (instead) wins race $4$ and loses race $3$.  Call this group B.

Consider $\displaystyle p_4 \times q_3 = \frac{1}{11} \times \frac{3.3}{4.3}$. 
Denote this as $R$.

Consider $\displaystyle q_4 \times p_3 = \frac{10}{11} \times \frac{1}{4.3}$. 
Denote this as $S$.

As a shortcut to computing the collective sum of the $3$ races in group B, you can take the collective sum of the $3$ races in group A, and multiply it by $\displaystyle \frac{R}{S} = \frac{3.3}{10}.$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need the probabilities that the horse will win each particular race. Those are not necessarily the reciprocals of the odds, in fact if they *were*, the betting house would go bankrupt!

If the odds are $A/B$, this means with probability $p$ of winning you get $A/B$ dollars (pounds etc.) per each invested dollar, and with $1-p$ you lose your invested dollar, so the betting house gets on average $(1-p)-p\frac{A}{B}$, and for it to break at least even they need:

$$(1-p)-p\frac{A}{B}\ge 0$$

$$1\ge p\left(1+\frac{A}{B}\right)=p\frac{A+B}{B}$$

$$p\le \frac{B}{A+B}$$

So, if the odds are, say, $4:1$, this means that the probability of winning is *at most* $1/5=20\%$ (as per the betting house's judgement). Of course, you are betting that they are wrong, which they may be, so $p=\frac{B}{A+B}$ is probably a reasonable estimate of the probability of winning.

Now, let your probabilities be $p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4, p_5$. All you need to calculate to check the probability of winning in *exactly* three out of five races is:

$$p_1 p_2 p_3(1-p_4)(1-p_5)+p_1 p_2(1-p_3)p_4(1-p_5)+\ldots+(1-p_1)(1-p_2)p_3 p_4 p_5$$

(there are $10$ terms above - one per each choice of three out of five races). There may be more compact ways to write this down (using $\sum$ and $\prod$ notation) - but this won't help much, so I am not going to do it.

You may tidy up the above expression a bit: it is equal to:

$$S(5,3)-4S(5,4)+10S(5,5)$$

where:

$$S(5,3)=p_1p_2p_3+p_1p_2p_4+p_1p_2p_5+p_1p_3p_4+p_1p_3p_5+p_1p_4p_5+p_2p_3p_4+p_2p_3p_5+p_2p_4p_5+p_3p_4p_5$$
$$S(5,4)=p_1p_2p_3p_4+p_1p_2p_3p_5+p_1p_2p_4p_5+p_1p_3p_4p_5+p_2p_3p_4p_5$$
$$S(5,5)=p_1p_2p_3p_4p_5$$

are the *symmetrical polynomials* in five variables of degree $3, 4, 5$, respectively. One way of getting those is expanding the polynomial:

$$(X-p_1)(X-p_2)(X-p_3)(X-p_4)(X-p_5)=X^5-S(5,1)X^4+S(5,2)X^3-S(5,3)X^2+S(5,4)X-S(5,5)$$

i.e. finding the coefficients multiplying $X^2$, $X$ and the constant term - as per [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

**Exercise**: In your case, we have

$$p_1=\frac{1}{1+2.2}=0.3125$$
$$p_2=\frac{1}{1+4}=0.2$$
$$p_3=\frac{1}{1+3.3}\approx 0.23256$$
$$p_4=\frac{1}{1+10}\approx 0.09091$$
$$p_5=\frac{1}{1+5}\approx 0.16667$$

Now try expanding the following polynomial (I've used [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-1%2F3.2%29%28x-1%2F5%29%28x-1%2F4.3%29%28x-1%2F11%29%28x-1%2F6%29) for that):

$$(X-0.3125)(X-0.2)(X-0.23256)(X-0.09091)(X-0.16667)$$

to get

$$X^5 - 1.00263 X^4 + 0.388746 X^3 - 0.0726216 X^2 + 0.00649665 X - 0.000220226$$

i.e.

$$S(5,3)\approx 0.0726216, S(5,4)\approx 0.00649665 , S(5.5)\approx 0.000220226$$

and, finally

$$S(5,3)-4S(5,4)+10S(5,5)\approx 0.04883726\approx 4.9\%$$